# how to change document root in xampp

Tags: xampp

In earlier version of xampp, inside `httpd.conf` I changed:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/">
```

into

```
DocumentRoot "D:/"
<Directory "D:/">
```

So my files are on a more safe place.

In current version (`3.2.2`) if I do that I can go to `localhost` (`D:/`), but if I try to open some folder containing `index.php` I'm getting redirection to `https...` and warning - `there is no permission...`

This happens in all browsers (win 7).

Any help?